# data link socket read outgoing packets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I wrote a simple program using raw data link socket to read packets going through my local ethernet interface, say, eth0. Here is the loop structure of my program. The complete source code is attached at the end of this post. The program is based on [C Language Examples of IPv4 and IPv6 Raw Sockets for Linux](http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html). I compiled the source code on CentOS 7.

```
while(1)
{

    if ((bytes = recvfrom(recvsd, recv_ether_frame, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen)) < 0) {
        perror ("recvfrom() failed ");
    }

    if ( (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame, dst_mac, 6)) && (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame+6, src_mac, 6)))
    {
        printf("Outgoing >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");

        dumpMemory(recv_ether_frame, bytes, 16);
    }

    if ((0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame, src_mac, 6)) && (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame+6, dst_mac, 6)) )
    {

        printf("Incoming >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");

        dumpMemory(recv_ether_frame, bytes, 16);
    }
}
```

In the above code, `recvsd` is a data link socket (PF_PACKET) created with `socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))`. I though the statement `recvfrom(recvsd, recv_ether_frame, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen))` only reads the data incoming to my local machine, like a L3 socket (PF_NET) does. But to my surprise, it also reads data originating from my local machine and outgoing to other hosts. I though this is a behavior of promisc mode, but I got the same result after I make sure the interface eth0 is not in promisc mode.

Is this a well-defined behavior of data link sockets?

The complete source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <errno.h>




// Define some constants.
#define ETH_HDRLEN 14  // Ethernet header length
#define IP4_HDRLEN 20  // IPv4 header length
#define ICMP_HDRLEN 8  // ICMP header length for echo request, excludes data

using namespace std;


void dumpMemory(void* data, size_t len, int bytes_per_row)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", ((unsigned char*)data)[i] );
        if (0==(i+1)%bytes_per_row) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, status, datalen, send_frame_length, tmpsd, recvsd, bytes, timeout, trycount, trylim, done;
    char *interface, *src_ip, *dst_ip, *rec_ip;
    struct iphdr *send_iphdr, *recv_iphdr;
    struct icmp send_icmphdr, *recv_icmphdr;
    unsigned char *src_mac, *dst_mac, *recv_ether_frame;
    struct sockaddr_ll device;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr from;
    socklen_t fromlen;


    if (argc != 6) {
        printf("Example usage: ./a.out <dev_name>  <src_mac> <src_ip> <dst_mac> <dst_ip>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate memory for various arrays.
    src_mac = (unsigned char*)malloc (6);
    dst_mac = (unsigned char*)malloc (6);
    recv_ether_frame = (unsigned char*)malloc (IP_MAXPACKET);
    interface = (char*)malloc (40);


    strcpy (interface, argv[1]);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &src_mac[0], &src_mac[1], &src_mac[2], &src_mac[3], &src_mac[4], &src_mac[5]);
    src_ip = argv[3];
    struct in_addr src_in_addr;
    if (inet_pton(PF_INET, src_ip, &src_in_addr) <=0 ) {
        perror("inet_pton failed ");
        exit (1);
    }

    sscanf(argv[4], "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &dst_mac[0], &dst_mac[1], &dst_mac[2], &dst_mac[3], &dst_mac[4], &dst_mac[5]);
    struct in_addr dst_in_addr;
    dst_ip = argv[5];
    if (inet_pton(PF_INET, dst_ip, &dst_in_addr) <=0 ) {
        perror("inet_pton failed ");
        exit (1);
    }

    // Submit request for a socket descriptor to look up interface.
    // We'll use it to send packets as well, so we leave it open.
    if ((tmpsd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
        perror ("socket() failed to get socket descriptor for using ioctl() ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Use ioctl() to look up interface name and get its MAC address.
    // memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    // snprintf (ifr.ifr_name, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
    // if (ioctl (tmpsd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
    //   perror ("ioctl() failed to get source MAC address ");
    //   return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    // }

    // Copy source MAC address.
    //memcpy (src_mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);

    snprintf (ifr.ifr_name, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
    if ((ifr.ifr_ifindex = if_nametoindex (interface)) == 0) {
        perror ("if_nametoindex() failed to obtain interface index ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Get the current flags that the device might have */
    if (ioctl (tmpsd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
    {
        perror ("Error: Could not retrive the flags from the device.\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    /* Set the old flags plus the IFF_PROMISC flag */
//    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
//    if (ioctl (tmpsd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
//    {
//        perror ("Error: Could not set flag IFF_PROMISC");
//        exit (1);
//    }
//    printf ("Entering promiscuous mode\n");
    close(tmpsd);

    if ((recvsd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
        perror ("socket() failed to obtain a receive socket descriptor ");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt (recvsd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof (ifr)) < 0) {
        printf("setsockopt(...SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,...) failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    while(1)
    {
        memset (recv_ether_frame, 0, IP_MAXPACKET * sizeof (uint8_t));
        memset (&from, 0, sizeof (from));
        fromlen = sizeof (from);

        if ((bytes = recvfrom(recvsd, recv_ether_frame, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen)) < 0) {
            perror ("recvfrom() failed ");
        }

        if ( (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame, dst_mac, 6)) && (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame+6, src_mac, 6)))
        {
            printf("Outgoing >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");

            dumpMemory(recv_ether_frame, bytes, 16);
        }

        if ((0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame, src_mac, 6)) && (0==memcmp(recv_ether_frame+6, dst_mac, 6)) )
        {

            printf("Incoming >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");

            dumpMemory(recv_ether_frame, bytes, 16);
        }
    }

    // Close socket descriptors.
    close (recvsd);


    // Free allocated memory.
    free (src_mac);
    free (dst_mac);
    free (recv_ether_frame);
    free (interface);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is - yes.
But why are you surprised?

Comment: I used to program with L3 sockets, and as far as I know, recvfrom(sock...) is supposed to only return incoming packets on sock. I was expecting the same behavior for L2 socket. That is why I was surprised at first.